# Linguagem MQL4 (Ordens BUY e SELL)

Tags: c, mql4

alguém tem conhecimento dessa linguagem "MQL4", ela é baseada em C e é usada particularmente por um programa de cotação de bolsa de valores. Caso alguém conheça, minha pergunta é a seguinte: Como faço ordens de BUY e SELL para Opções Binárias?

Comment: Documentação em http://docs.mql4.com/

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente obrigado a todos que de alguma forma contribuíram com a questão, recebi recentemente um e-mail da [TraderTools FX](http://www.tradetoolsfx.com/), que desenvolveu a extensão para o MetaTrader4 para operar Opção Binária(OB) diretamente na plataforma, e recebi um exemplo bem básico, mas o suficiente para compreender como funcionam as ordens para OB.
Segue abaixo o código disponibilizado.

```
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //|                                                    BO Expert.mq4 |
    //|                                     Copyright 2013, TradeToolsFX |
    //|                                      http://www.tradetoolsfx.com |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #property copyright "Copyright 2013, TradeToolsFX"
    #property link      "http://www.tradetoolsfx.com"

    //--- input parameters
    extern int TotalOrders = 5;
    extern double Lots = 1;
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| expert initialization function                                   |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    int init()
      {
    //----

    //----
       return(0);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| expert deinitialization function                                 |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    int deinit()
      {
    //----

    //----
       return(0);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    //| expert start function                                            |
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
    int start()
      {
       int cnt, ticket, total,cnty, cmd;

       total=OrdersTotal();
       if(total<TotalOrders) 
       {
          for(cnty=0; cnty < TotalOrders - total;cnty++)
          {
             if((cnty%2) == 0)
                cmd = OP_BUY;
             else
                cmd = OP_SELL; 

             ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),cmd,Lots,Bid,3,0,0,"BO exp:60");        
          }
       } 
       return(0);
      }
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```